# Verify that $R$ is the cover relation of a partially ordered set.

Tags: combinatorics

I am recently learning about Partial Ordering and for some reason, I am finding it difficult to grasp all the ideas involved in it.

**Problem:**  Let $X=\{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$ and let the relation $R$ on $X$ be defined by $aRb$, $bRc$, $cRd$, $aRe$, $eRf$, $fRd$. Verify that $R$ is the cover relation of a partially ordered set, and determine all linear extensions of this partial order.

**My Attempt:** I picked up how to draw a Hasse diagram and so this is the picture I drew:

[image]

I am guessing that the diagram is somehow involved in the proof, but I am not sure. Any hints on how to proceed after this step will be much appreciated.

Comment: What is a cover relation for a poset? How is this defined?

Comment: $xRy$ if and only if $x<y$, with no $z$ existing in $X$ such that $x<z<y$.

Comment: Cannot you just define $P$ as the symmetric and transitive closure of $R$ and then show you're done?

Comment: Wait, I do not understand what you are saying... What do you mean by symmetric and transitive closure?

Comment: The smallest relation containing $R$ that is both symmetric and transitive, so add all $xSx$ and $aRc$, $aRd$ etc. whenever we have $xRy$ and $yRz$ we add $xSy, ySz , xSz$ etc. to  form $S$. Then show $S$ is a partial order.

Answer (score 3):

I think taking the reflexive and transitive closure of $R$ should do it, but it's a tedious check. So define $S$ on the same set by $aSa, bSb, cSc, dSd ,eSe, fSf, aSb, bSc, aSc, cSd, aSd, aSe, eSf,aSf, fSd, eSd, bSd$ (I think these are all) and check that $S$ is a partial order and then check that $xSy$ and no $z$ with $xSz$ and $zSy$ implies $xRy$ and vice versa. It's almost trivial from the picture and construction, really. There is probably a criterion for $R$ to be the covering relation of a poset.

The linear extensions are distinguished by how we order $b,c,e,f$ in a linear way, respecting $b < c$ and $e< f$. Options are $ b < c < e < f$, $b < e < c < f$, $b < e < f < c$ and $e < f < b < c$ and $e < b < f < c$, $e < b < c < f$ as far as I can see, so 6 options.

Comment: symmetric? I think you had something else in mind (reflexive, antisymmetric).

Comment: We do need $xSx$ for all $x$. In this case, maybe antisymmetry comes for free.

Comment: But we do not need $aSb\implies bSa$ (symmetry).

Comment: For me, symmetry = $xRx$ for all $x$, and antisymmetry $xRy$ and $yRx$ implies $xRx$. The fomer is also called reflexive I think. Asymmetric is $xRy$ implies not $yRx$. @drhab

Comment: What you call [symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_relation) is reflexivity.

Comment: @drhab I'll follow more common usage.

Comment: Goed voornemen! :-)

Answer (score 1):

In this context it is handsome to make use of the concept **strict partial order**, which is by definition a relation that is irreflexive and transitive. If you define $\overline R$ as the transitive closure of $R$ then  it is not difficult to verify that in your case $\overline R$ is irreflexive. Also $\overline R$ is transitive so it is a strict partial order. Just like a partial order it has a covering relation $C$ and evidently we have $C\subseteq R$. It remains to be shown that also $R\subseteq C$, and this can be done by brute force. The covering relation of strict partial order $\overline R$ is evidently the same as the covering relation of the corresponding partial order $\overline R\cup\triangle$, where $\triangle:=\{\langle x,x\rangle\mid x\in X\}$.

---

In general:

- If $P$ is a strict partial order then $P\cup\triangle$ is a partial order.
- If $P$ is a partial order then $P\setminus\triangle$ is a strict partial order.